# Adding TileJSON layer hangs browser

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

Adding my custom TileJSON causes the browser to hang.

Custom TileJSON: https://data.madronus.com/landcraft/assessment-data/dNfg1lNQF1Zaz-0VpTYxq/20/tms/tilejson.json

Adding the source like this:

```
map.addSource(`tiles-source`, {
  type: 'raster',
  url: <URL>,
})
```

And the layer like this:

```
this.map.addLayer({
  id: 'tiles',
  type: 'raster',
  source: 'tiles-source',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that MapboxGL (JS) will crash if any of your Lng/Lats are set as strings rather than floats. Updating the TileJSON to floats for `center` and `bounds` fixes this.